# Which assemblies conflict in "found conflict between different versions"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I am getting "found conflict between different versions" from one of my projects.

How do I find out which assemblies are actually in conflict?

Comment: Are you seeing something like this: 103>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depend)

Answer (score 1):

Build the solution and check the output window - you should be able to see in there.

Comment: I should be able to ... but I don't. (See my comment to @Jono).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depend as noted above

Comment: Check your CSPROJ files.  I didn't see any addt'l info in the output window, but I did see an incorrect reference path in the CSPROJ that I was seemingly unable to remove via the VS GUI.  Removed, reloaded, and rebuilt w/o issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error list window (CTRL+W,E) should show which assemblies were in conflict. Failing that, the output window (CTRL+W,O) will show which of the conflicting assemblies was arbitrarily picked for the build.

Comment: It only shows a warning that doesn't specify which assemblies are conflicting.

Comment: To use a phrase I coined a while back, "it works on my machine." Are you using the RC version of VS2010? And is it a C# project?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, RC version, and native C# project.

Comment: How about using msbuild.exe directly from the command line? 
<code>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30128\msbuild.exe MyTest.csproj</code>
It might not be in the bit that's highlighted yellow, but scan the output for "No way to resolve conflict between..."

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depend as noted above

Answer (score -1):

[alt text http://img82.imageshack.us/img82/2484/vs2010sucks2.png](http://img82.imageshack.us/img82/2484/vs2010sucks2.png)

Usually, double clicking the error takes you to the line causing problems. There you can check the method calls being called from referencing assemblies.

--Edit--
But, I agree with the last comment; link error does not throw on the particular line of code.

Comment: @Downvoter: Any reasons for the downvote you might like to add?

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted, but your answer does not seem relevant to my question.

Comment: @Ripper234: `How do I find out which assemblies are actually in conflict?` Usually when you double click the error line in the output window, the IDE takes you to line causing the error. The intention of this post was to help you get to that line and see the conflicting assemblies. Also see, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/73d1b418-0b2d-4649-b491-21b39a468457

Comment: I can confirm that when you get an "Unable to resolve conflict" message, double clicking in the output window does nothing.

Comment: Output window is simply a text dump... how could clicking that possible do anything other then select some text???

Comment: In many cases, this error gives you a link within Microsoft.Common.Targets, instead of the actual assembly in conflict.

Comment: @daveL VS is really quite smart, try it out