# How can I resolve a reference when its .NET dependency has a version mismatch?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, azure-storage

I am trying to include the WindowsAzure.Storage library in my Windows Phone 8 project, but it cannot resolve the reference because of this error:

> Warning   3   The primary reference "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "3.9.0.0" in the current target framework.   standrighthere

Comment: If the library (`System.Net.Primitives`) is backward compatible add a binding redirect.

Comment: Have you not got .NET 4 installed?

Comment: @mattytommo Yes. I have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: also check this link to see if the steps here will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depen

Comment: @dtryon How do I check if it is backwards compatible?

Comment: I think you are adding wrong reference Please try to add from this library https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Samples/ for WP8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [What’s new for Microsoft Azure Storage at TechEd 2014](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/14/what-s-new-for-microsoft-azure-storage-at-teched-2014.aspx) - the latest 4.0 .NET Client Library includes Windows, Phone and RT support.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

What version of the client library are you using? This Nuget package enable you to work with Windows Phone projects - [nuget storage-preview](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage-Preview). See [storage team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-storage-build-2014.aspx) for more information on the final release.