# MSB3247: Found conflicts... error for EnttityFramework 4.4.00 to 5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

This occurs in ASP.Net MVC 4 project.

I found an excellent suggestion to view MSBuild detailed output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depen).  Seems like **System.Web.Providers.dll** is referencing 4.5.0.0 causing this error.

I attempted a Binding redirect in web.config under runtime -> assemblyBinding

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

When I rebuilt the project, I still got the below message:

> Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EntityFramework,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version
>   "4.4.0.0" [] to Version "5.0.0.0"
>   [C:\Rhipheus\Cloudlene.Rhipheus\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll]
>   to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

I extended redirect to 4.5.0.0:

> Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EntityFramework,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version
>   "4.5.0.0" [] to Version "5.0.0.0"
>   [C:\Rhipheus\Cloudlene.Rhipheus\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll]
>   to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

Same message but now the version reported is 4.5.0.0.  I took the redirect up to 4.9.0.0 to no avail (same message with just the version's bumped matching my redirect).

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?  I appreciate in advance for not closing this as not constructive ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Once I included 5.0.0.0, the warning went away.  Guess, binding redirect must not only redirect older references but the 'primary reference' too.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```