# Precompile an ASP.NET application - i am getting Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, aspnet-compiler

When i build my project targeting .NET 4.0 in visual Studio 2010, i get the following Warning but with no any other error or warning, so the projects runs.

***C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
  AssemblyFoldersEx location: "{Registry:Software\Microsoft.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}"***

However, i cannot recompile the project with aspnet_compiler

***Microsoft (R) ASP.NET Compilation Tool version 4.0.30319.18408
Utility to precompile an ASP.NET application
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(0): warning : The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a failure: myProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. The dependencies are: System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. You should either ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is that of the dependent assembly.
d:\Projects\Release\SourceCode\web.config(55): warning CS0108: 'ProfileCommon.GetProfile(string)' hides inherited member 'myProjectName.Core.ProfileCommon.GetProfile(string)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ec305f94\ca5ad86b\App_Web_i51pzwht.0.cs(28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'myModel' does not exist in the namespace 'MedicalService.ViewModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post [Resolving MSB3247 - Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depen/9950089#9950089) lead me to the utility below which helped me solve the issue.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/asmspy-little-tool-to-help-fix-assembly.html