# MSBuild and <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences />

Tags: c#, msbuild

The "Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" contains this block:

```
    <!-- 
  Workaround MSBuild issue that prevents System.Runtime 2.5 and System.Threading.Tasks 2.5 from
  satisfying indirect dependencies on System.Runtime 1.5 and System.Threading.Tasks 1.5 respectively.  
-->
<AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>false</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
```

What actually "AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences" do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It maps directly to the `AutoUnify` parameter of the [`ResolveAssemblyReferencs`-Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9ad3f294.aspx).

Excerpt from the documentation:

> This parameter is used for building assemblies, such as DLLs, which
>   cannot have a normal App.Config file.
>
> When true, the resulting dependency graph is automatically treated as
>   if there were anApp.Config file passed in to the AppConfigFile
>   parameter.This virtual App.Config file has a bindingRedirect entry for
>   each conflicting set of assemblies such that the highest version
>   assembly is chosen.A consequence of this is that there will never be a
>   warning about conflicting assemblies because every conflict will have
>   been resolved.
>
> When true, each distinct remapping will result in a high priority
>   comment showing the old and new versions and that AutoUnify was true.
>
> When true, the AppConfigFile parameter must be empty
>
> **When false, no assembly version remapping will occur
>   automatically**.When two versions of an assembly are present, a warning
>   is issued.
>
> When false, each distinct conflict between different versions of the
>   same assembly results in a high-priority comment.These comments are
>   followed by a single warning.The warning has a unique error code and
>   contains text that reads "Found conflicts between different versions
>   of reference and dependent assemblies".

The highlighted sentence seems to explain the comment in `Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Targets` you refer to.

(This parameter also influences the not uncommon [MSB3247 warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871073/21567).)

The defaults for the `AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences` is therefor set to `false` for certain types of "exe" assemblies and to `true` for other assembly types (see `%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0*\Microsoft.Common.Targets` for details).

Comment: Christian,thank you for your answer!  Now, i hope, i can resolve my problem.