# C# VS 2013 Warning message: msb3247 will not go away even after adding bindingRedirects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I've been working on a project that's getting these warning messages after building

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

I've tried using AsmSpy to check which references are conflicting and set the build output to Diagnostic to verify, added bindingRedirect to app.config and those warning messages still aren't going away.

Need help, thanks.

Comment: You have seen this right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871073/resolving-msb3247-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-depen

Comment: Seen that already :(

Comment: Needs more information.. Which assempblies, which versions do they have?

Comment: some custom assemblies, but for the native ones, System, System.Core, and mscorlib...

I got the the bindingsReference in place in the App.config file

Also, the warning message is referring to Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.Targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
Followed the article below to automatically enable bindingRedirect.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx

I still got conflicts based on diagnostic build log for
mscorlib
System
System.Core