# VS2005: Found conflicts between different version of the same dependent assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

What does it mean if I receive this warning?  Does it mean the project is referencing the same assembly from different files?

Comment: Are you using any third party products? Check this post: http://www.blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=03fe209c-db64-4a04-9adc-cec25b36f68b for possible answer

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806/warning-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can commonly occur if a "project reference" has somehow reverted to a file reference. If you have a project that is referencing other projects, try removing those references and re-adding them. It can also occur if two dependent projects each reference a different version of a third assembly.