# Deployment optimization failed, how to fix?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I am developing a windows phone app (The solution consist of two projects, i am referring one project in the other)   with `sqlite` as the Database. The App runs only on the ARM platform. In `Debug` mode the app runs fine on the device  and all functionalities of the app appears working but when i change it to `Release` mode i get the following error

> Deployment optimization failed due to an invalid assembly. Rebuild
>   your source projects and try again.

I rebuild the project several time but getting the same error on `Release` mode. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806/warning-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assemb) and tried it but couldn't solve my issue., I also removed all the unused assemblies in my `.cs` files. how can i fix this ? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you install package from nuget ?

Comment: Yes i have added some..

Comment: Then you refer Sqlite.dll from install package and In which project you add reference of sqlite, In your windows phone project ?

Comment: The packages and sqlite.dll are added to the main project,(The startup project)

Comment: In your sqlite package can you see Sqlite.dll and Sqlite.winmd ?

Comment: I added sqlite under references the file is actually Sqlite.winmd and not sqlite.dll

Comment: Please share your screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution !! In release mode i removed `.dll`s  one by one and built the solution when error occurs i added them back. In my case the error was because of a `dll` from nuget , i fixed that and as next step i configured `Debug` Mode to be Simiar to `Release` mode by right clicking on the projects and selecting properties and then changing configurations same for both `Debug` and `Release` modes...