# How do I clear warning MSB3276 in first out-of-the box Xamarin project in Visual Studio Community for Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

Just installed Visual Studio Community for Mac along with homebrew and openssl, and then created my first solution: droid + iOS + backend service using .Net Core.

Without touching the code, first build produces a bunch of build warnings. The first one seems ominous:

> Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
>   property to true in the project file. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

So, read the link and added:

`<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>`

to each *existing* PropertyGroup in both the .droid and .ios projects. Saved all, rebuilt all, and get the exact same set of warnings.

Note that the app seems to work just fine...debug-runs clean in Android and iOS simulators.

When I double click on the warning, it takes me to a place I'm pretty certain I don't want to be in: Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets, which is way down in bowels of the Mono installation.

So the questions are:

- Why am I getting these kinds of warnings in an out-of-the-box new project?
- Are these warnings going to cause me any real grief?
- What's the right way to clear these warnings?

I've done a lot of windows development with Visual Studio in Windows, but this is my first attempt to do Mac-side development, and so I can believe I horked something up, but I'm a bit lost. I've always been the sort that *needs* to clear any and all warnings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806/warning-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assemb)