# Suppressing MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Here is the scenario

`A.dll` references `B.dll (2.0.0.0)`

`A.dll` references `C.dll` and `C.dll` references `B.dll (1.0.0.0)`

Obviously, `msbuild` will invoke the warning below since `B.dll` versions conflict. Automatically it will pick the latest version since I denied creating `app.config` file automatically in csproj file.

`Warning: MSB3276 - Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"`

And I **do not want** to redirect anything since neither one will work with each other versions.

Question:

How do I get rid of this warning or **suppress** it ?

**Note**: Both assemblies will be installed in GAC at the time of installation process so runtime references will resolve just fine. Sadly, there seems no way to indicate `MSBuild` to let go of this warning.

Comment: MSBuild 15 / VS 2017 allows to build using `/nowarn:MSB3276`, not aware of any support for <15..

Comment: Is there a way to control this from csproj file instead for VS2017 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806/warning-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assemb)

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2017 / MSBuild 15, edit the project file and add the following to the `Project\ProprtyGroup` section:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>MSB3276</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Works on my instance of Visual Studio 15.9.11

Ritchie

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get rid of this warning or suppress it ?

This is a very stubborn warning but it is a valid warning. You can try to edit your project file and add this property group and setting to disable the warning:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note: This setting also covers other warnings about mismatch assembly, etc. MSB3270.